# Why does this function print out 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript

The `list` function below is supposed to list the names of the people in my `contacts` array.

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];

function printPerson(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
}

var list = function() {
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
        console.log(printPerson(contacts[i]));
    }
};

list;
```

However, instead of just printing out Bob Jones and Mary Johnson, I get:

```
Bob Jones
undefined
Mary Johnson
undefined
```

Can someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `printPerson` method writes to the console, but does not return any value, so in your `for`-loop where you have:

```
for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
    console.log(printPerson(contacts[i]));
}
```

It's also trying to write the return value of `printPerson` to the console, which is `undefined`.

To fix this, either drop the `console.log` from the `for`-loop *or* return a value from `printPerson` rather than writing to the console there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function printPerson(person) {
    return person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `printPerson` function writes to the console. It does not return a value explicitly. When a function without an explicit return value runs, it returns the `undefined` value. The console always tries to display the return value of a function after it runs, if an explicit value is not set, it returns the value `undefined`.